# Lock application orientation to landscape and sensor only

Tags: java, android, manifest

I understand how to lock the application into landscape mode using `android:screenOrientation= "lanscape"` but how can I lock it to use both landscape and sensor orientations, which allows me to switch between the landscape views and skip out the portrait views. I found somewhere there is an option for sensorLandscape orientation mode but don't know how to set this in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `sensorLandscape` is a newly added manifest option only available for Android 2.3. Link [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html#api). Perhaps you could add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity, and in your `onConfigurationChanged` method, handle the changes only if you're at a 90 or 270 degree orientation?